# Scala future fallback method clarification

Tags: scala, future

After seeing this statement on `Scala` future `fallback` method I was trying to permutate the `success` and `failure` variable values. I'm not able to follow with this case

> Future fallbackTo combines 2 Futures into a new Future, and will hold the successful value of the second Future if the first Future fails.

I have a simple code like :

```
val success = Future{new Exception("Failure from success")}
val failure = Future{'c'}
val fallBackOperation = success.fallbackTo(failure)
val result= Await.result(fallBackOperation, Duration.Inf)
println(result)
```

### This code snippet outcome is

`Future(Success(java.lang.Exception: Failure from success))`

As per the documentation

I was excepting `failure` variable as outcome how ever I'm getting the outcome from `success` variable. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to `throw` your exception to fail first future